# try and catch with a count

Tags: try-catch

If this statement has no records will it return 0 or does the "try" feature cause it to fail and fall thru to the "catch" statement after an if/else statement.  The "if" statement checks for the counter to be 1 and then an else for any other number.  It seems to fail if there are no matches.  The "else" statement never executes  Why?

try {Integer counter = [ Select count()                                                                                FROM E_mail__c 
Where E_mail_Address__c = :email.fromAddress ];

Comment: Your code doesn't include any if-else statements, so that part of your question is a bit unclear to me. As for your query, you're actually getting the `array[0]` results of a `list<AggregateResults>` query which @Mark Pond seems to have covered why there could be a null pointer exception that a try-catch block could contain. .

Answer (score 4):

The `counter` variable will contain 0 if there are no matches found by the query as you've got it written.

If `email` is `null` however `email.fromAddress` will cause a null pointer exception to be thrown and be handled by the respective `catch` block.